# upper bound on sum of number of divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logarithms

**Problem:** show that $$d(1)+d(2)+d(3)+\cdots d(n) \leq n \log(n)$$ where $d(i)$ is the number of divisors of $i$.

**My attempt:** I used $$\sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor =\sum_{i=1}^n d(i) \implies \\\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n d(i)}{n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor}{n} \le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$$ It is well known that $\log n \le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} \le 1+\log n$ which makes me unable to proceed forward. Can we make some change in my approach to make it correct?

Comment: Are you sure the inequality is correct? Can you evaluate both sides for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$? EG For $n = 1$, the RHS is 0, so the inequality is clearly incorrect. $\quad$ If by divisors, you meany divisors smaller than $i$, then the inequality is true and your approach works.

Comment: Yeah, it’s not true for $n=2,$ either.

Comment: Nor does it work for $n=3,4,5,6.$

Comment: The inequality might never be true.  The LHS - RHS is asymptotic to $(2\gamma -1) n$.  Since $2\gamma-1 > 0$  the claim is also false for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: thanks everyone. I am very sorry for posting a wrong question, but i posted it as it was given in a textbook, now i feel quite sure that $d(i)$ here means the number of divisors of $i$ **less that $i$**.